# What is android.uid.system: 1000 and why is it displayed?

Tags: java, android, react-native, networking

I have an app where I configure a passpoint/hotspot 2.0 network on the device.
It all works fine but when I preview the configured network I see the SSID followed by `Connected via android.uid.system: 1000`.

Can this be changed to say it is connected by the app name?
Keep in mind this was tested via Internal Testing on Google Play Console. (In case that is the issue)

This is on Android 11 using the WiFi Suggestions API.

[image]

Comment: `android.uid.system: 1000` is self explanatory, it is a system process. _"Can this be changed to say it is connected by the app name?"_ No.

Comment: For Android 10 and lower, I use a different library/class (WifiManager) to configure a network profile.  That says it is connected via the app name.  Hence why I was curious why it is different here - I know its a different OS version and library that I am using.  Thanks for the swift response.